# How to decode large file without runing out of memory?

Tags: rust, character-encoding

I need to convert a ~4GB IBM866 encoded xml file into UTF-8. I tried [this](https://crates.io/crates/iconv)
and [this](https://crates.io/crates/encoding_rs) crates, but with both of them I run out of memory.

I tried to do it this way:

```
fn ibm866_to_utf8(ibm866: &[u8]) -> Result<String, MyError> {
    use encoding_rs::IBM866;
    let (utf8, _, had_error) = IBM866.decode(ibm866);
    if (had_error == true) {
        Err(MyError::DecodingError)
    } else {
        Ok(utf8.to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let path = "ibm866_file";
    let mut file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let mut vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(file.metadata().unwrap().len() as usize);
    file.read_to_end(&mut vec);
    let utf8_string = ibm866_to_utf8(&vec).unwrap();
    // write to file
}
```

I also tried to iterate file by lines like this:

```
fn main() {
    let path = "ibm866_file";
    let mut file = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut utf8_string = String::new();
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let utf8_line = ibm866_to_utf8(line.unwrap().as_bytes())
        utf8_string = format!("{}{}", utf8_string, utf8_line.unwrap());
    }
    // write to file
}
```

But it panics when `reader` meets non UTF-8 character.

How to decode large files properly?

link to file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fHFS5GWPhApoNRl3CRK-pRMNthIakcZY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Would you mind pasting a link to an example file? To try out possible solutions.

Comment: Why not try encoding_rs_io?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the *streaming* functionality of `encoding_rs`.

This requires a bit of boilerplate code, though, to properly feed the chunks read from a file into the conversion function.

This code seems to work on a simple example, as well as on your multi-GB large `legends.xml` file and reports no conversion errors.

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{Read, Write},
};

use encoding_rs::{CoderResult, IBM866};

const BUF_SIZE: usize = 4096;

struct ConversionBuffers {
    buf1: [u8; BUF_SIZE],
    buf2: [u8; BUF_SIZE],
    buf1_active: bool,
    content: usize,
}

impl ConversionBuffers {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            buf1: [0; BUF_SIZE],
            buf2: [0; BUF_SIZE],
            buf1_active: true,
            content: 0,
        }
    }
    fn move_leftovers_and_flip(&mut self, consumed: usize) {
        let (src, dst) = if self.buf1_active {
            (&mut self.buf1, &mut self.buf2)
        } else {
            (&mut self.buf2, &mut self.buf1)
        };

        let leftover = self.content - consumed;
        dst[..leftover].clone_from_slice(&src[consumed..self.content]);

        self.buf1_active = !self.buf1_active;
        self.content = leftover;
    }
    fn append(&mut self, append_action: impl FnOnce(&mut [u8]) -> usize) {
        let buf = if self.buf1_active {
            &mut self.buf1[self.content..]
        } else {
            &mut self.buf2[self.content..]
        };

        let appended = append_action(buf);
        self.content += appended;
    }
    fn get_data(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
        if self.buf1_active {
            &self.buf1[..self.content]
        } else {
            &self.buf2[..self.content]
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut decoder = IBM866.new_decoder();

    let mut file_in = File::open("test_ibm866.txt").unwrap();
    let mut file_out = File::create("out_utf8-2.txt").unwrap();

    let mut buffer_in = ConversionBuffers::new();
    let mut buffer_out = vec![0u8; decoder.max_utf8_buffer_length(BUF_SIZE).unwrap_or(BUF_SIZE)];

    let mut file_eof = false;

    let mut errors = false;

    loop {
        if !file_eof {
            buffer_in.append(|buf| {
                let num_read = file_in.read(buf).unwrap();
                if num_read == 0 {
                    file_eof = true;
                }
                num_read
            });
        }

        let (result, num_consumed, num_produced, had_error) =
            decoder.decode_to_utf8(buffer_in.get_data(), &mut buffer_out, file_eof);

        if had_error {
            errors = true;
        }

        let produced_data = &buffer_out[..num_produced];
        file_out.write_all(produced_data).unwrap();

        if file_eof && result == CoderResult::InputEmpty {
            break;
        }

        buffer_in.move_leftovers_and_flip(num_consumed);
    }

    println!("Had conversion errors: {:?}", errors);
}
```

---

As @BurntSushi5 pointed out, there is the [`encoding_rs_io`](https://docs.rs/encoding_rs_io) crate that allows us to skip all the boilerplate code:

```
use std::fs::File;

use encoding_rs::IBM866;
use encoding_rs_io::DecodeReaderBytesBuilder;

fn main() {
    let file_in = File::open("test_ibm866.txt").unwrap();
    let mut file_out = File::create("out_utf8.txt").unwrap();

    let mut decoded_stream = DecodeReaderBytesBuilder::new()
        .encoding(Some(IBM866))
        .build(file_in);

    std::io::copy(&mut decoded_stream, &mut file_out).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: This is what `encoding_rs_io` does for you.